# Wrong size UIWindow and not correspond uiviews

Tags: size, ios9, uiwindow

[image]

I have problem with UIWindow size , in xcode 6 and ios 8 its worked fine, but when i start app from xcode 7 and ios 9 it did not correspond uiviews

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

So i found problem , new xcode 7 off my LaunchScreen.xib and app was not full screen.

Answer (score 0):

From https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5572, by Rincewind:

> If you don't have any launch images, and you don't have a launch nib or storyboard, then you are declaring that you don't support any screen sizes aside from 320x480 (on iPhone/iPod). This has always been the case and is not new. Older Xcode Projects automatically generated a Default-568h.png to support 4" screens. This may have been invisible if you've used an iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus, because if you had a Default-568h.png for 4" screen support, these devices scaled your app rather than letter boxed them.
>
> A brand new project should not demonstrate any of these issues.